# How to prevent QWidget::keyReleaseEvent from being called when a QAction's shortcut is typed

Tags: qt, qwidget, qaction

In my QMainWindow subclass, I have several QActions with QKeySequence shortcuts. I have also reimplemented `QWidget::keyPressEvent` and `QWidget::keyReleaseEvent` in the main window.

If I type one of the shortcuts on my keyboard (e.g., Ctrl + C), `keyPressEvent` is not called in my main window, which makes sense because the relevant action wants that event instead. However, `keyReleaseEvent` *is* called for some reason. Is there any way to prevent that, or at least easily detect in `keyReleaseEvent` if the event matches one of the main window's shortcuts, so that I can ignore the event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug. I filed a report [here](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-29587).